# Updating state in parent ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a problem with managing states in ReactJS. I have created a component called "Step" that consists of a text input field and a button. The button's function is to create a "sub step" so you have a structured list like this:

- parent step

  - child step

    - child-child step
- parent step2

and so on.

Each step has 2 state variables: it's description (what's inside of the text input) and a list of it's own sub-steps. In my main component in which I create the parent steps I have a state array which contains all the parent steps (which contain a list of their sub steps, which contain list of their sub steps and so on).

The problem is that when I try to log this main array. For every first-level 
step it shows that it has no description and no sub-steps even though it does.

My goal is to simply log the array and get all the steps (as a main step or  inside of an array of another step)

This is how I add a main-level step in the main component:

```js
export default class DynamicForm extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        title: '',
        actors: [],
        steps: [],
        systemActorAdded: false,
    };

    let url = "http://localhost:8080";
}

addStep = () => {
    const currentSteps = this.state.steps;
    currentSteps.push(new Step());
    this.setState({steps: currentSteps});
};

removeStep = () => {
    const steps = this.state.steps;
    steps.pop();
    this.setState({steps: steps});
};
```

This is the Step component that should contain its description and all of his substeps:

```js
export default class Step extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        subSteps: [],
        description: '',
    };
}

createSubStep = () => {
    let subSteps = this.state.subSteps;
    subSteps.push(new Step());
    this.setState({subSteps});
};

removeSubStep = () => {
    let subSteps = this.state.subSteps;
    subSteps.pop();
    this.setState({subSteps});
};

handleInputChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({description: event.target.value});
};

render() {
    const subSteps = this.state.subSteps.map((element, index) => {
        return (
            <Step key={index}/>
        )
    });

    return (
        <div className="text-and-button">
            <input type="text" className="form-control animated lightSpeedIn step"
                   placeholder="Wprowadź krok" onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-success step-button animated lightSpeedIn"
                    onClick={this.createSubStep}>
                <i className="fas fa-plus"/>
            </button>
            {this.state.subSteps.length > 0 ?
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger step-button animated lightSpeedIn"
                        onClick={this.removeSubStep}>
                    <i className="fas fa-minus"/>
                </button> : null}

            <div className="full-width">
                {subSteps}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

And this is how I log the contents of steps array from the main component:

```js
getStepsArray = () => {
        let stepArray = this.state.steps;
        let steps = [];
        for (let step of stepArray) {
            steps.push(step.state);
        }
        return steps;
    };
```

**EDIT:** this is what I would expect as an example output of the whole table:

```
"steps":[
{
  "description":"asd",
  "subSteps":[
    {
      "description":"asd",
      "subSteps":[
        {
            "description":"hello"
        }
        ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "description":"aaaa"
}
```

]

Comment: Please include your code in text format instead of as images.

Comment: Done, sorry for inconvenience

Comment: You can't get step.state like you did, Step in your state are object not the component himself. You should maybe use refs if you want to do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to separate view (render of a component) and data.

Answer (score 0):

I would try it this way:  Since your substeps appear to be related to the main state, create the add and remove substep methods in the main component and pass them down to the Step component. Set up your main state so that state.steps is an array of objects (steps), each including substeps.

Map through the substeps in main as well and pass "substeps" down as a prop.

Since the state.description is coming from the input in the Step component (i.e., it's controlled), you could pass that back up to main state as a parameter as well.  When you log the stepArray, you can then drill down to the substeps as step.substeps.

Hope that helps some!

Comment: I'm not sure if I got that right. What you meant is that I should keep all the steps (regardless of the level) in the main array?

Also, don't know how the mapping should look. I have to maintain the hierarchy of the substeps so it was natural for me to have it like I do now and just print the whole array once.

Comment: I've added the expected outcome to my question to clarify what I want to get

Comment: In general you want to separate view (render) and data, unless it's a controlled component where the input reflects the state. You're adding data to the Step component that would better be managed in the main component. Also, to clean it up, you may want to consider separating out your view even further so Step renders the parent step and then maybe even "Substep1" and "Substep2" given the levels. Give the Step component an "add" button, give Substep1 an "add" and a "delete" button. Substep2 gets a "delete" button. Add will add a substep a level down. Delete would delete the step itself.

Comment: Separating the logic from the view is what I would have been doing from the begginig, but since I'm still a React newbie I didn't know how.

Comment: Currently all of the steps have an "add" button, since every step can have its substeps. The "delete" button is bound to the parent step and deletes his sub-steps one by one from the bottom (pop). The main idea is that every step can potentially have infinite substeps, so I cannot see how this "Substep1" and "Substep2" idea can be used here. I'm certainly missing something, but it may be the language barrier since English isnt my main language